# Leg Exercises with Dumbbells?

Tags: weightlifting, legs, dumbbells

I have a pair of the Bowflex SelectTech 1090 dumbbells and a bench.  They are great for upper-body workouts, but I'm looking for a way to use them for leg exercises as well.

What leg exercises can I do with dumbbells for strength-training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of exercises that you can try with just a pair of dumbbells.  However, if your goal is for strength training, then you must follow the progressive overload  principle, paying close attention to the rep ranges (3-8).

With this being said, depending on the max weight that you have (I believe they go up to 90 lbs), you can try these exercises:

1. Dumbbell Squat
2. Dubbbell Lunges
3. Dumbbell Sumo Deadlift
4. Dumbbell Stiff-legged Deadlift
5. Dumbbell Single Leg Squat

These should be plenty for you to start out with.  Again, for strength training, you should aim for 3-8 reps. For muscle hypertrophy, aim for 8-15 reps.  For both, then aim for 6-12.  Good luck!